# Perform async action only when Option<> is Some

Tags: language-ext

In a piece of code using [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) library, I can perform an async action only when the `Option<>` intermediate result is actually filled:

```csharp
async Task<Option<MyEntity>> FindEntityAsync(string entityId)
{
    Option<MyEntity> entityOpt = await GetEntityAsync(entityId);

    if (entityOpt.IsSome)
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync(entityOpt.First());
    }

    return entityOpt;
}

// Task<Option<MyEntity>> GetEntityAsync(string entityId) { ... }

// DoSomethingAsync could either be:
//   Task DoSomethingAsync(MyEntity entity) { ... }
// or:
//   Task<Unit> DoSomethingAsync(MyEntity entity)
```

I'm looking for a more *idiomatic* way (for such library) to achieve the same.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```csharp
// look ma! No async/await here
Task<Option<MyEntity>> FindEntityAsync(string entityId)
{
    Task<Option<MyEntity>> result =

        from entity in GetEntityAsync(entityId)

        from _ in DoSomethingAsync(entity).Map(Some)

        select entity;

    return result;
}
```

I experienced some `LanguageExt.ValueIsNoneException` when the `Option<>` is `None`.

Ideally I'd like to user an `IterXxx` type of operator in order to *traverse* the wrapped `Option<MyEntity>` only when there is something:

```csharp
Task<Option<MyEntity>> FindEntityAsync(string entityId)
{
    Task<Option<MyEntity>> result = GetEntityAsync(entityId);

    result.IterXxxx(async entity => await DoSomethingAsync(entity));

    return result;
}
```

but I cannot find any suitable signature working with an async action. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

There is special type `OptionAsync<T>` for combining two monads - Option and Async. 
For more info please refer to github - https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/206

Comment: Not sure which particular bit of that API you are suggesting. In the meantime I've found `Option<>.IfSomeAsync()` that helps being a little terser. Also, I could not find any `IterAsync` available with that type. I'm on v2.1.18

Comment: github issue says that "v2.0.40 on nu-get now has an OptionAsync<A> type.". So you need to update version on your side

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed your version. It seems you have higher version then needed. For more info about API please refer to this comment - https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/206#issuecomment-289801396